# How to apply the multiresolution modifier from sculpt mode?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm kind of new to blender, I've been using it for about two weeks but haven't used sculpt mode much.

Today I decided to sculpt the head of a character, using a *multiresolution* modifier to help get the geometry I wanted, but I can't apply the *multiresolution* while in sculpt mode and if I leave sculpt mode my object turns back into a low-poly model.

If I apply the *multiresolution* in object mode then all of my sculpting is gone for good. How in the world do I keep my sculpting work while in something like edit or object mode?

Answer (score 12):

You need to raise the ***Preview*** value to match the ***Sculpt***, and apply the modifier in object mode.

[image]

Comment: Darn this didn't work for me. I'm using version 2.78a if that matters. Any idea why this doesn't work? I'm in sculpt mode and am trying to "apply" the multires modifier, just like the OP. But getting the same error as if preview was at zero.

Comment: Ahhh. nevermind. Once I went back into object mode, I was able to keep all the clay strips and applied the modifier and they stayed.

Comment: @Azurespot Thanks for the comment, I'm glad you were able to figure it out. I've updated the answer to clarify that you need to apply the modifier in object mode.